# How to display only time in datepicker control in wpf

Tags: wpf, datepicker

I tried to display only time in datepicker control

in my application i want the user to select only time from the datepicker.
i don't know how to display only time in datepicker if any one have any idea
give some code sample

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Extended WPF Toolkit`, in that you will find a ready `TimePickerControl`.

you can download from this link

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TimePicker&referringTitle=Home

Comment: hi i download the dll and but i don't how to call it in xaml.give some information how to use